# need additional title in apa6

Tags: titles, apa6

I am writing a short report and the title page has to look like this:

> Short Report
>
> Reactions to ...
>
> Author
> Affiliation

I solved it q-n-d by using author as stand-in for "Reactions to..." , let affiliation empty (by using "`~`") and then used `\note` to enter author and affiliation. but by doing this, I only get "short report" on the first content page (repeat title). I would prefer to have "Reactions to...", so is there a way to put "Short Report" *above* the regular title on the front page? or do I have to input the repeat title also manually?

Of course I can add the code:

```
\title{Short Report }
\shorttitle{Stigma ...}
\author{Reaktionen auf ...}
\affiliation{~  } 
\note{Henning \\ University of XyZ}
```

If I try a line break in `\title` i get various error codes like:

```
! Argument of \@sect has an extra }.
<inserted text>
\par
l.80 \maketitle
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything.
For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce
this error. If you simply proceed now, the `\par' that
I've just inserted will cause me to report a runaway
argument that might be the root of the problem. But if
your `}' was spurious, just type `2' and it will go away.
```

No idea what Texmaker wants to tell me here; a linebreak in `\note` works fine.

Comment: Can you add the code you're using up to now? It will be easier to play with it than to guessing.

Comment: What's wrong with putting `\title{Short Report\\Reactions to...}` and then setting the `\shorttitle{Reactions to...}`. This is exactly what the short title is for.

Comment: edited my first post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use two lines in the title and define a `\shorttitle`.

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % just to produce mock text

\begin{document}
\title{Short Report\\[\baselineskip]The real title}
\shorttitle{The real title}
\author{Henning}
\affiliation{University of XyZ}

\abstract{An abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Text}
\kant[1-20]

\end{document}
```

### First page (top only)

[image]

### Second and third page (top only)

[image]

---

If the `man` option is used, a simple measure can be taken:

```
\title{Short Report\protect\\[\baselineskip]The real title}
```

Comment: ok, i think i found the problem: your solution works perfectly. but ONLY in journal mode. but i have to hand in a manuscript. and there even your minimal example wont work... :((
(sorry i didnt mention that... didnt think the problem could be located there)

Comment: @henning Please, add the `\documentclass` line to your question and all the relevant information. But you probably just need `\protect` in front of ``\\`` in `\title`